# Android 23 (Marshmallow) and Higher permission Having a heck of a time

Tags: java, android-permissions, android-studio-2.3

First, Thank you very much for looking at this!
     I've been handed an app someone wrote before Marshmallow. I've fixed the Theme and SSL issues that came with Nougat but I'm having a heck of a time with Write to External Storage Permission or something associated. Debug is lacking or I'm not using it properly. This app creates a file onto the device and adds the ssl cert and login info in a folder called My Documents. 
     When I open the app it say network timeout right away. That message is from LoginActivity.java . I click ok then I get the Android pop up asking to allow permissions. I allow it. After that I put in the username and password and click login. It instantly gives the network timeout message from LoginActivity.java. LoginActivity.java is the Main Activity. If I click ok it's back to the login screen. All permissions are in the Android Manifest as well.

Maybe it's not from permissions but it works fine in version 22. I've worked on this 12 hours today and thought if you guys could help that'd be great. I'm a network engineer dabbling in Java so please excuse my question if it's "ugly".

I tried to find a line by line debug like I've done with phonegap but wasn't successful.

My Apps Main Activity LoginActivity.java and associated activity is LoginScreen.java and shown below.

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private String userName = "";
    private static final int PERMS_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blackactivity);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        new SSLHandler().execute();
        if(Variables.testing)
        {

        }
        if (hasPermissions()){
            // our app has permissions.
            try {
                attemptLogin();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                GUI.oneOptionDialog(this, e.toString(), "OK", false);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            //our app doesn't have permissions, So i m requesting permissions.
            requestPerms();
        }

    }


    //Begin Permission Methods
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private boolean hasPermissions(){
        int res = 0;
        //string array of permissions,
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        for (String perms : permissions){
            res = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(perms);
            if (!(res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestPerms(){
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            requestPermissions(permissions,PERMS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        boolean allowed = true;

        switch (requestCode){
            case PERMS_REQUEST_CODE:

                for (int res : grantResults){
                    // if user granted all permissions.
                    allowed = allowed && (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                }

                break;
            default:
                // if user not granted permissions.
                allowed = false;
                break;
        }

        if (allowed){
            //user granted all permissions we can perform our task.
            try {
                attemptLogin();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                GUI.oneOptionDialog(this, e.toString(), "OK", false);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            // we will give warning to user that they haven't granted permissions.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Storage Permissions denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    //End Permission Methods



    private void attemptLogin() throws IOException {
        String filepath = Variables.fileFolder + "/login.txt";
        File tempFile = new File(filepath);
        if (!tempFile.exists()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginScreen.class));
            finish();
        }
        String username = "";
        String passwordHash = "";
        String salt = "";
        boolean fileExists = false;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    fileInputStream);
            reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            username = reader.readLine();
            passwordHash = reader.readLine();
            salt = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();
            userName = username;
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginScreen.class));
            finish();
        }

        fileExists = true;

        if (fileExists) {
            try {
                LoginTask login = new LoginTask();

                login.execute(username, passwordHash, salt);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }

    private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        Boolean success = false;
        Boolean timedOut = false;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            try {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            if (timedOut) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        LoginActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Network Timed Out").setTitle("Notice");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                        LoginScreen.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                if (result) {
                    Variables.storeTechName(userName, LoginActivity.this);
                    Variables.assignTechName();
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            LoginScreen.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this,
                    "Loading...", "Logging you in...");
            mProgressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                URL json = new URL(Variables.urlPrefix + "/Login.svc/input?a="
                        + params[0] + "&b=" + params[1] + "&c=" + params[2]);
                HttpsURLConnection jc = (HttpsURLConnection) json
                        .openConnection();
                jc.setConnectTimeout(Variables.timeoutTimeLimit);
                jc.setSSLSocketFactory(Variables.context.getSocketFactory());
                InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(
                        jc.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);

                String line = reader.readLine();

                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(line);

                success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("LoginMethodResult");
                jc.disconnect();

                reader.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                timedOut = true;
            }

            return success;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

LoginScreen.java

```
public class LoginScreen extends Activity {
    private String userName;
    private static final int PERMS_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        if (!SSLHandler.loaded) {
            new SSLHandler().execute();
        }

        // Creates login and name files and attempts to log in
        Button createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createbutton);

        createButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamefield)).getText()
                        .toString().isEmpty()
                        || ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordfield))
                        .getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    GUI.oneOptionDialog(LoginScreen.this,
                            "Missing field entries", "OK", false);
                } else {
                    createLoginFile();
                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamefield)).setText("");
                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordfield)).setText("");
                    attemptLogin();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private boolean hasPermissions(){
        int res = 0;
        //string array of permissions,
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        for (String perms : permissions){
            res = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(perms);
            if (!(res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestPerms(){
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            requestPermissions(permissions,PERMS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        boolean allowed = true;

        switch (requestCode){
            case PERMS_REQUEST_CODE:

                for (int res : grantResults){
                    // if user granted all permissions.
                    allowed = allowed && (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                }

                break;
            default:
                // if user not granted permissions.
                allowed = false;
                break;
        }

        if (allowed){
            //user granted all permissions we can perform our task.
            createFiles();
        }
        else {
            // we will give warning to user that they haven't granted permissions.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Storage Permissions denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    private void createFiles() {

    }


    private void attemptLogin() {
        String username = "";
        String passwordHash = "";
        String salt = "";
        boolean fileExists = false;
        try {
            String filepath = Variables.fileFolder + "/login.txt";
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    filepath));
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    fileInputStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            username = reader.readLine();
            passwordHash = reader.readLine();
            salt = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();
            userName = username;
            fileInputStream.close();
            fileExists = true;
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            GUI.oneOptionDialog(LoginScreen.this,
                    "Login file does not exist. Please enter login info.",
                    "OK", false);
        }
        if (fileExists) {
            try {
                LoginTask login = new LoginTask();
                login.execute(username, passwordHash, salt);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        Boolean timedOut = false;
        Boolean success = false;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            try {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            if (timedOut) {
                GUI.oneOptionDialog(LoginScreen.this, "Network Timed Out",
                        "OK", false);
            } else {
                if (result) {

                    Variables.storeTechName(userName, LoginScreen.this);
                    Variables.assignTechName();
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginScreen.this,
                            MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                } else {
                    GUI.oneOptionDialog(LoginScreen.this,
                            "Login Failed. Please try again.", "OK", false);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginScreen.this,
                    "Loading...", "Logging you in...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                URL json = new URL(Variables.urlPrefix + "/Login.svc/input?a="
                        + params[0] + "&b=" + params[1] + "&c=" + params[2]);
                HttpsURLConnection jc = (HttpsURLConnection) json
                        .openConnection();
                jc.setConnectTimeout(Variables.timeoutTimeLimit);
                jc.setSSLSocketFactory(Variables.context.getSocketFactory());
                jc.setConnectTimeout(Variables.timeoutTimeLimit);
                InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(
                        jc.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);

                String line = reader.readLine();

                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(line);

                success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("LoginMethodResult");

                jc.disconnect();
                reader.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                timedOut = true;
            }

            return success;

        }
    }

    private void createLoginFile() {
        try {
            File dir = new File(Variables.fileFolder);
            if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            String filepath = Variables.fileFolder + "/Login.txt";
            String username = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamefield))
                    .getText().toString();
            String password = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordfield))
                    .getText().toString();
            String salt = new RandomString(20).nextString();
            String passwordHash = Variables.sha256(password + salt);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filepath, "UTF-8");
            writer.println(username);
            writer.println(passwordHash);
            writer.println(salt);
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            GUI.oneOptionDialog(LoginScreen.this, e.toString(), "OK", false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: This turned out to not be permissions. It was SSL Ciphers.

Comment: Here's how I fixed the ssl issue. I ran two patches on the server side server 2003r2 and did some registry edits rebooting after each step. 
Do them at your own risk.

[Link 1 is 1st Microsoft Patch/Fix 262679] https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/948963

[Link 2 is 2nd Microsoft Patch/Fix 192447] https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/948963


Here are the instructions below and the link. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3050509/improving-cipher-security-in-windows-server-2003-sp2 "This is the Link from Microsoft for full details Article ID: 3050509 from Mar 24 2015"